# Showing / Hiding nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, menu, show-hide

Hi and I hope someone can help.

I'm building a website which will have a main horizontal tabbed menu and a secondary horizontal tabbed menu when one of the items above is clicked. Off the second tabbed menu there will be another sub menu which bring up links where, once clicked, will reveal content to the right. Pictorially this is shown below.

[image: tabbed menu]

To try and get the logic working I've built some very simple test pages to try out showing and hiding divs but I only seem to be able to get the equivalent of   the first sub menu showing.

Because (ultimately) this will be a large site with multiple pages I've organised the first menu in the root folder of the site, the sub menu in a sub folder called 'pages' and the sub sub menu in a folder called 'pages/resource_pages'.

Here's my test code, 1 the top level - nest.html in the root folder

```
<body onload="openLevel2();"> <!-- done to initially hide unwanted divs -->
<div id="home">Nested Div Test</div>
</br>
<div id="div1"> <a href="#" title="Nest1" class="level1Hyperlink" onclick="openLevel2(event,'nest1')">Nest 1 - located in root folder</a> </div>
<div id="nest1" class="level1HiddenDiv"> 
  <script>$( "#nest1" ).load( "pages/nest2.html" );</script> 
</div>
</body>
```

Second level code - nest2.html in the pages folder

```
<body>
<div id="div2"> <a href="#" title="Nest2" class="level2Hyperlink" onclick="openLevel3(event,'nest2')">Nest 2 - located in root/pages folder</a> </div>
<div id="nest2" class="level2HiddenDiv"> 
  <script>
$( "#nest2" ).load( "pages/resource_pages/nest3.html" );
</script> 
</div>
</body>
```

Third level code - nest3.html in the pages/resource_pages sub folder

```
<body>
<div id="div3"> <a href="#" title="Nest3" class="level3Hyperlink" onclick="openLevel4(event,'nest3')">Nest 3 - located in root/pages/resource_pages folder</a> </div>
<div id="nest3" class="level3HiddenDiv"> 
  <script>
$( "#nest3" ).load( "ca_nearby.html" );
</script> 
</div>
</body>
```

Here' my javascript

```
function openLevel2(evt, scriptName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, level1Hyperlink, level1HiddenDiv;

    // Get all elements with class="level1HiddenDiv" and hide them
    level1HiddenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("level1HiddenDiv");
    for (i = 0; i < level1HiddenDiv.length; i++) {
        level1HiddenDiv[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="level1Hyperlink" and remove the class "active"
    level1Hyperlink = document.getElementsByClassName("level1Hyperlink");
    for (i = 0; i < level1Hyperlink.length; i++) {
        level1Hyperlink[i].className = level1Hyperlink[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(scriptName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Script for showing resource letter menu tabs
function openLevel3(evt, resourceName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, level2Hyperlink, level2HiddenDiv;

    // Get all elements with class="level2Hyperlink" and hide them
    level2HiddenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("level2HiddenDiv");
    for (i = 0; i < level2HiddenDiv.length; i++) {
        level2HiddenDiv[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="level2Hyperlink" and remove the class "active"
    level2Hyperlink = document.getElementsByClassName("level2Hyperlink");
    for (i = 0; i < level2Hyperlink.length; i++) {
        level2Hyperlink[i].className = level2Hyperlink[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }   

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(resourceName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Script for showing resource letter sub menu tabs
function openLevel4(evt, letterName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, level3Hyperlink, level3HiddenDiv;

    // Get all elements with class="level3HiddenDiv" and hide them
    level3HiddenDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("level3HiddenDiv");
    for (i = 0; i < level3HiddenDiv.length; i++) {
        level3HiddenDiv[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="level3Hyperlink" and remove the class "active"
    level3Hyperlink = document.getElementsByClassName("level3Hyperlink");
    for (i = 0; i < level3Hyperlink.length; i++) {
        level3Hyperlink[i].className = level3Hyperlink[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }   

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(letterName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Thanks Jonas. The page loads fine, the link to the 2nd link works fine, thereafter it doesn't work.

Comment: At first, debug your code. Add alerts in multiple lines and observe, if it is like you expected. Also look into the browsers console. Then minify your code, to improve browser loading time and readability.

Comment: Asyncly loading additional code can cause problems, i would try to remove this

Comment: Thanks again Jonas. Must be honest didn't realise the significance of your asynch comment. Although I don't fully understand it yet I think that could be my issue. Currently checking it out [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: Yeah, html5rocks! Because i dont know your complete structure, i cannot really help you. I will write an answer now, wich will may help you. If a code "doesnt work" it normally trows an error that can be easily debugged trough the console

Answer (score 1):

Messing around with a lot js and html, you can run into problems concerning readability, so i would prefer a pure js solution, wich will make it more readable /better debuggable:

```
var structure={
    name:"level1",
    links:[
         {
         name:"level2-1",
         links:[
                     {
                      name:"level3-1",
                      links:[]
                     },
                     {
                     name:"level3-2",
                     links:[]
                     }
                  ]
          },
          { name:"level2-2", ...
          }
       ]
     };

function show(element){
//add the name to header
 document.GetElementById("header").innerHTML=element.name;
linkcontainer=document.getElementById("linkcontainer");
linkcontainer.innerHTML="";
counter=0;
element.links.forEach(function(link){
    l=document.createElement("span");
    l.onclick=(function(element,counter){
         //this should create an onclick element
      return  function(){show(element.links[counter])};
    })(element,counter);
    l.innerHTML=element.links[counter].name;
    linkcontainer.appendChild(l);
    counter++;
    }
    }
 window.onload=function(){show(structure);}
 </script>
 <div id="header">should contain name</header>
 <div id="linkcontainer">should contain links</div>
```

This should create:

```
Level1
Level2.1
Level2.2
```

And if you click on level 2.1:

```
Level2.1
Level3.3
Level3.4
```

I had problems with the onclick statement: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/referencedvariables.html

Comment: Thanks again Jonas, you're a bit of a gem as both your posts have caused me to sit back and think about what I'm up to. TBH it's been about 3 years or so ago since I did any javascript but I think I've worked it out now. I think that I need to move all my javascript out of the html file and move it to a separate js file where it should get read when the base index.html file gets loaded. Thereafter it will become available for the subsequent files that get loaded through the load commands. My thanks again.

Comment: @Roger W : no worries. However, moving the js into a file will not change much...